# Where/how to include geography helper method - Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, model, helper

I have a helper method, `states_list`,  that is returning an array of US states that I want to access in a few different places of my Rails app including:

- User model: `validates :state, inclusion: { in: states_list }`
- User model spec: test for this validation

These will be reused elsewhere in addition to the User model. I am wondering where the proper place to store this helper method is, and how to access it from the model and tests. (My initial thought was in a GeographyHelper file inside the helpers directory, but I read that those are meant specifically to be view helpers...) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably be best served by putting your `states_list` method in its own module and including it in your User model. The advantage of creating a module is that your concerns are nicely separated and reusable (in case you want to validate states in other models.

1) Create a place to put your module by going into your `/lib` directory and creating a directory for your custom modules (we'll call it `custom_modules` here).

2) Create your module file: `/lib/custom_modules/States.rb`

3) Write your module:

```
module CustomModules

  module States

    def states_list
      #your logic here
    end

  end
end
```

4) Include your new States module in your User model or any other model where you'd like this functionality.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  include CustomModules::States

  validates :state, inclusion: { in: states_list }
end
```

Comment: Hmmm, it's not working - getting: `undefined local variable or method `us_states' for #<Class:0x007fecdc244930>`. Including the custom module in my test file and calling the method seems to work there, but when I try to do it in the model file, I get that error.

Comment: Try making sure your app is loading the module by adding the following line to your `application.rb`: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` Make sure to let me know if this works so I can edit the answer. If this doesn't work, then there's something else going on and you should open a new question.

Comment: Hmmm, changing `include` to `extend` fixed it. I did some reading about how `include` is for adding methods to an instance of a class and `extend` is for adding class methods...? Should my `states_list` method be a class method or an instance method?

Comment: `extend` doesn't seem right to me. `include` should make `us_states` available to the instance of `User` that includes it. `extend` will make `us_states` available to the class `User`. There may be something else going on with your code, but since you haven't supplied any, it's hard to say (and it would have to be resolved in another question, since the information I provided is accurate for what you gave). So did you edit `application.rb` or not?

Comment: Yes, I had your exact code and already had `config.autoload_paths << "#{config.root}/lib"` in `application.rb`. I decided it makes more sense to make `states_list` a class method - `def self.states_list` and then call it from the model with `validates :state, inclusion: { in: CustomModules::States.states_list }` which also works. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can store this method in either `application helper` or in `user model` it self.